# Mongodb find docs without associated doc

Tags: mongodb, database

I have a mongo database with a users collection and a profile collection. I need to find all users that do not have a profile. The docs are associated with an email address.

Comment: I've tried googling for some clues but couldn't find anything. Can this be done with just a query or do I have to code it?

Comment: You'll have to code it, as there is no join in mongodb. Something like db.users.find({}, {'email': 1}).forEach(function(email){... code to find email in profile and act accordingly})

Comment: Feel free to add your solution as answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.user.find().forEach(function(o) {
    if(db.profile.find( { email: o.email } ).length() == 0) {
        print(o.email);
    };
})
```